# Create user (email/password) without automatic login on Firebase 3

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication

I have an administration page where I used to create new users there (with additional data creation in the Database). I need this additional data to enforce security for those users

Upgrading to Firebase 3 and the updated AngularFire, I see now that the newly created user using **is signed in automatically**. This blocks the whole process, because the new user is (obviously) not allowed to grant itself permissions.

This is a particularly stupid change and invalidates the whole page.
I see after searches that there is no direct way to return to the previous logical behavior ; is anyone has found a workaround ?

Comment: The linked question did contain a working (and clever) workaround.